# different classes in Java

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to make different classes and make instances in the main class then run the program just that simple, but i get this error:

```
shka.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        ahmed c = new ahmed("Shika");
        ^
  symbol:   class ahmed
  location: class shka
shka.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        ahmed c = new ahmed("Shika");
                      ^
  symbol:   class ahmed
  location: class shka
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

And here is the code
shka.java:

```
public class shka {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting.. ");
        ahmed c = new ahmed("Shika");
        // c.name = "Shika";
        System.out.println(c.name);
    }
}
```

ahmed.java:

```
public class ahmed {
    public String name;

    // Constructor
    // This = self in python
    public ahmed(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void msg() {
        String h = "BATTA";
        System.out.println("HELLO, " + h + " This is the other class");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Comment: No it didn't @JCWasmx86

Comment: Are both files in the same directory? Try to compile with `javac *.java`, to compile all files

Comment: Yes they are, i'm compiling using 'java filename.java', does it make difference?

Comment: Yea, that link kind of assumes a level of knowledge of (basic) Java that it seems that you don't have yet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't have `package` statements in the classes.

A class without a `package` statement is implicitly declared in the default (anonymous) package.  But a class in the default package is not implicitly imported by another class in the default package.  AND you can't *explicitly* import from the default package ... because it has no name.

Solution:

1. [Read about Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html).  This is the **most important step**.
2. Add `package` statements
3. If the classes are in different packages (your choice!) add `import` statements as required.