# Cannot find symbol error even if they are on the same directory in Java

Tags: java

I have two files in the same directory namely `Main.java` and `Functions.java`

The content of `Main.java` is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.next();

        Functions you = new Functions(s);

        System.out.println("Your name is " + you);
    }
}
```

And `Functions.java`:

```
public class Functions {
    public String name;

    public Functions(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I manually compile and run them on my terminal. So this is what I did:

`javac folder1/folder2/*.java`
And after
`java folder1/folder2/Main.java`

But it gives me an error of this:

```
error: cannot find symbol
Functions you = new Functions(s);
symbol:   class Functions
```

Even though they are on the same directory, it will still give an error.

Edit: I interchanged my code for compiling and running. Sorry for that.

Comment: First, run Functions.java file, then run Main.java

Comment: Your first command to compile `Functions` should be `javac`

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Newer java you can just run a .java file. In that case, it will not find Function.class because you have it in a subdirectory. It would need to be in a package in that case. I suspect you can just go to the folder `folder2` and type `java Main` and it should run the compiled version, and it will find Function.class because it is on the classpath.

Comment: @matt I am using OpenJDK 13.0.1. I tried changing my working directory to where all the .java files are. Still, when I try to run in my terminal this `java Main.java`, the same error shows up.

Comment: @JohnCymmer Leave off the .java, doing that assumes 'single-source-mode' avoid that at first. Check my answer, do the '.class' files exist after you run javac? If you change directory to folder2 then you can just run `java Main`, again *not Main.java but Main*.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872247/different-classes-in-java/62872469

Answer (score 0):

1. run `javac Main.java`
2. run `java Main`

**Note 1:** You don't need to explicitly compile the files which are being used in the file you're compiling. If Java compiler sees, that you're using class `B` in the class `A`, Java will implicitly compile all the classes (including class `B`) when compiling the container class (class `A`, in this case).

**Note 2:** If you're using JDK >=11, then you can just compile+run the program with one command. [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330), **Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs**, is one of the new features introduced in the JDK 11 release. So, you can just run `java ClassName.java`.

Comment: Tried it but still won't work. It still cannot find the Class but thank you for the Notes.

Comment: JEP 330 is specifically about "single-file source-code programs". Since OP has spread their code over 2 files, it won't help here! And I think that's actually the problem here.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I know that it's about single-file. I gave him the solution for the first problem, and then, as a bonus, suggested what he might also find useful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is classpath.

```
folder1
| folder2
| | Main.java
| | Functions.java
```

After you run `javac folder1/folder2/*.java` you'll have class files.

```
folder1
| folder2
| | Main.class
| | Main.java
| | Functions.class
| | Functions.java
```

Since your classes are *not in a package* then folder2 needs to be on the classpath. To run main.

```
java -cp folder1/folder2 Main
```

Notice that I left off the `.java` on the name of the class.

If you don't want to supply the -cp argument (sets the classpath) you can `cd folder1/folder2` then you'll be in the folder with the class files. You can just type.

```
java Main
```

I tried this with your java files. When it works you won't see any output until you press enter.